# iTunes doesn't recognize iPhone's remote app

Tags: iphone, itunes, macos, wifi, remote.app

## A bit of info about my configuration

```
OS X: Mavericks
iOS: 7.1.1
Hardware: iPhone 5s and BacBook Pro (Late 2013) 
They are both on same Wifi network.
```

## Problem

iTunes doesn't recognize [iPhone's remote app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remote/id284417350?mt=8) in any way.

## What I tried

- Reinstalled OS X
- Reinstalled Remote app on iPhone
- Reinstalled iOS
- Resetted Wifi router (There is no problem with router. It worked with same configuration about half year ago)
- Tried with and without home sharing
- Deauthorized and reauthorized iTunes
- Signed out of Apple account and signed in on iTunes
- Turned off OS X Firewall
- Reset iTunes configuration
- Tried to switch WiFi signal channel

Neither iTunes nor iPhone doesn't recognize each other. Any suggestions?

Comment: Two questions, what is the "iPhone's remote app", and have you tried to create an 'Ad-hoc' wifi network using your MBP, and use that as you WiFi connection for the iTunes.

Comment: @CousinCocaine Remote app:  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remote/id284417350?mt=8

Comment: @Patience Ah, that one. It is most likely your router than. I had similar issues and only got it to work on my Apple router. You will notice that creating an Ad-hoc accespoint with your mbp will fix your issue.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question. I have the same configuration as you.

`OS: Mavericks
iOS: 7.1.1. 
Hardware: iPhone 5s and MBP Late 2013 
They are both in same wifi network.`

This is what I did:

I selected "Create Network" from the wireless icon in the menu bar. I did not specify a password. I was able to use the iPhone Remote app without failure. Since then, I've reconfigured it with a password and it also works without error.

Comment: Lol, so I need to exit current router's wifi to mbps network? Sorry but this is not solution

Comment: @TuralAliyev This is a known issue with several routers. Apple has not officially announced a list of compatible devices. After researching many forums and Apple's support page, I was left with the aforementioned workaround. I am frustrated with Apple's configuration as I've had several incompatibility issues.

Comment: @TuralAliyev, Dark_Cyber is right. You said the router wasn't the issue, but we are still not certain. Try the ad-hoc network, if that works, then your router IS the issue.

Comment: @CousinCocaine Like I mentioned in my answer, I had the same issue as TuralAliyev. It wouldn't work until I tried the ad-hoc network option. My DLink router WAS the issue, but I still believe that Apple should be able to configure their product/application/devices to work with most devices. Considering that I tested this on two different routers: a Dlink and a Linksys router. Both are pretty popular routers.

Comment: @TuralAliyev and @Dark_Cyber; unfortunately this is a common issue and affects me as wel :(